# Rotating an object with quaternion

Tags: opengl, rotation, quaternion, glm

I have a question in regards to using quaternions for the rotation of my graphics object.

I have a `Transform` class which has the following constructor with default parameters:

```
Transform(const glm::vec3& pos = glm::vec3(0.0), const glm::quat& rot = glm::quat(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    const glm::vec3& scale = glm::vec3(1.0))
{
    m_pos = pos;
    m_rot = rot;
    m_scale = scale;
}
```

In my `Transform` class calculate the `MVP` as follows:

```
glm::mat4 Transform::GetModelMatrix() const
{
    glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), m_pos);
    glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4_cast(m_rot);
    glm::mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0), m_scale);

    return translate * rotate * scale;
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I use `const glm::quat& rot = glm::quat(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` my object appears normal on screen. The following image shows it:
[image]

However if I try to use for example `const glm::quat& rot = glm::quat(glm::radians(90.0f), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)` (rotating on y axis by 90 degrees) my object appears as if it has been scaled. The following image shows it:
[image]

I can't figure out what is causing it to become like this when I try to rotate it. Am I missing something important?

If it's of any relevance, the following is how I calculate my view matrix:

```
glm::mat4 Camera::GetView() const
{
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(m_pos, m_pos + m_forward, m_up);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `glm::quat(float, float, float, float);` constructor doesn't do what you think it does. It sets the values directly.

The values of the quaternion `(w, x, y, z)` are in order: the cosine of half the angle, the sine of half the angle times the x coordinate of the normalized rotation axis, and the same for the y and z components.

So instead you want to use `glm::quat(cos(glm::radians(90.0f/2)),0,sin(glm::radians(90.0f/2))*1,0);` or after inlining the result of the trig: `glm::quat(sqrt(1/2),0,sqrt(1/2),0);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain what the constructor actually does? Also is there a way to initialize the quaternion for every axis based on your answer? Thanks

Comment: Something in your answer must be wrong. The `(0,0,1,0)` quaternion represents a 180-degree rotation.

Comment: oh right it's the half angle slipped my mind...

Answer (score 14):

You should probably use `glm::angleAxis()` ([documentation here](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/api/a00174.html#ga37ae19405f1ccf766f27e4fcd035d859)):

```
glm::quat rot = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(90.f), glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f));
```